# boolean value is not updating in the function

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to update a Boolean value declared in build method using a function which is being called on onPressed event.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DatabaseFunctions databaseFunctions = new DatabaseFunctions();
    bool isLiked = false;

    updateLikes() async{
      if(!isLiked){
        isLiked = true;
        await databaseFunctions.updateLikes(postId, likeCount+1);
      }else{
        await databaseFunctions.updateLikes(postId, likeCount-1);
        isLiked = false;
      }
    }
    return IconButton(
              onPressed: (){
                updateLikes();
                print("like status: $isLiked");
              }, 
              icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.heart),),
            }
```

the function updateLikes is updating a collection in the database and trying to switch the isLiked value.

The database function:

```
databaseFunctions.updateLikes(String postId, int likeCount) async{
    return await firestore.collection('posts')
    .doc(postId).update({'likes': {'likeCount' : likeCount}});
  }
```

The problem is the value of isLiked is not changing and the number of likes in the database keeps increasing on clicking the button.

Comment: put  updateLikes(); inside a setState method and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving these outside of the "build()" method:

1. the "updateLikes()" method
2. the " isLiked" variable

Also add "await"  before calling the " updateLikes" method.

Let me know if these workout for you

Answer (score 1):

defining variable inside `build` function is incorrect, you should move it outside the `build` method. this is due to everytime flutter rerender your widget this parameter will reinitialize in the build method. Also, use `setState` to change the state of the widget as follow:

```
bool isLiked = false;

updateLikes() async{
      if(!isLiked){
        isLiked = true;
        await databaseFunctions.updateLikes(postId, likeCount+1);
      }else{
        await databaseFunctions.updateLikes(postId, likeCount-1);
        isLiked = false;
      }
      setState((){});
    }
    

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DatabaseFunctions databaseFunctions = new DatabaseFunctions();
    return IconButton(
              onPressed: (){
                updateLikes();
                print("like status: $isLiked");
              }, 
              icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.heart),),
            );
```